# Poisson brackets over a Kaehler manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let be a Kaehler manifold $(M, h, J)$ and the brackets:
$$
{\rm tr}(R)(df, dg)   = \{ f,g \}
$$
with $f,g$, two functions and $R$, the riemannian curvature as a $2$-form in the endomorphisms of the tangent bundle; ${\rm tr}(R)={\rm Ricc}(.,J.)$. The so-defined brackets are Poisson brackets. (We have the Jacobi identity.) Can we define Hamiltonian flows like geodesics?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand which trace you take, but the Riemannian curvature is always trace-free, Levi-Civita connection is unimodular. So you bracket is always a Poisson bracket, namely the trivial one...?

Comment: In a Kaehler framework, the Einstein equations can be expressed as $tr(R)= \omega$, with $R$ the Riemann's curvature and $\omega$ the symplectic form. You can consult for more informations "Einstein Manifolds" by Arthur Besse.

Comment: I take a Kaehler manifold and define ${\rm tr}(R)={\rm ric}(.,J.)$ with the same question over the brackets...

Comment: Just to mention: my previous comment refers to the original version of the question, which the OP has changed completely by now.